# Особенное слово "галифе"

Tags: грамотная-речь, заимствования, единственное-множественное-число

Я всегда считала, что слово **галифе** имеет множественное число.
Но вот встретилось такое предложение, которое заставило меня призадуматься.

*Был он не в парадном мундире генералиссимуса, как на фотографии в студии, а в мягких и очень дорогих сапожках телячьей кожи, **простом сером галифе** и френче.*
[А. и С. Литвиновы. Мертвые не лгут](https://profilib.net/chtenie/9777/anna-i-sergey-litvinovy-mertvye-ne-lgut-43.php)

В некоторых словарях написано так:
[галифе́](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_udarenie/7056) [фэ], *неизм.; нескл., **мн.***

В некоторых – так:
[ГАЛИФЕ́](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/14565/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5) [фэ́], *неизм.; **мн. и ср.***

А как все-таки правильно? Помогите определиться, поделитесь своим мнением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часть словарей (напр. Ожегов - в отличие от Ушакова) *допускает* употребление этого слова с прилагательным ед. числа среднего рода. Причина в том, что в бытовой речи иногда проявляется склонность соотносить иностранное слово по форме (отвлечённо от его видового наименования "брюки/штаны")  с похожими по окончанию русскими словами определённого числа и рода. В одном из поздних интервью Розенталь допускал (не считая ошибкой) употребление слова "*кофе*" (формально мужского рода, по видовому наименованию "напиток") как существительного среднего рода. Наблюдается подобная же нестрогость со словами "виски", "мачете" и др. Видимо, и со словом "галифе" в неформальных случаях допустим расслабленный стиль.

Пример источника, поясняющего такую допустимость:

http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200501210

Comment: "Кофе" не потому считается/считалось мужским родом, что родовое наименование "напиток", а потому что раньше это слово было "кофий".

Comment: Я сослался на современные нормы, _поддерживающие_ сохранение мужского рода у слова "кофе" в рамках дискуссии о послаблениях. История же сложнее. Первопричиной был мужской род  формы "кофе" при первоначальном заимствовании слова из французского в самом начале 18 века, не прижившиеся же в конечном счёте формы "кофий" и "кофей" были лишь следствием, попыткой подвести русское окончание под род, употреблявшийся в литературных источниках, где доминировал вариант "кофе". Вот подробное исследование: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/istoriya-soglasovaniyapo-rodu-suschestvitelnogo-kofe-v-xix-xx-vv