# «Граффито» или «граффити»?

Tags: орфография, лексика, заимствования, единственное-множественное-число

*Умер художник Дмитрий Врубель, автор граффити "Братский поцелуй".*

Правильно ли использовать "граффити", а не "граффито" в этом предложении?

Имеется в виду, наверное, не стиль граффити, а рисунок в стиле граффити?

*Его освещали редкие фонари; в свете одного из них на стене дома мелькнуло размашистое граффити «LENINE EST MERDE». В. О. Пелевин, «Чапаев и пустота», 1996 г. [НКРЯ]*

_Как правильно говорить, когда речь идет об одном конкретном граффити. Красивый, красивое (граффити)?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Слово граффити употребляется как существительное pluralia tantum (имеющее
формы только мн. числа, ср. ножницы, брюки). Поэтому согласовать в единственном числе не получится_.

Если следовать "Грамоте", то надо бы написать

Умер художник Дмитрий Врубель, автор знаменитых граффити "Братский поцелуй".

В орфографическом словаре на "Грамоте":

граффити, нескл., мн. (надписи, рисунки)

граффито, нескл., с. (архит.; живопись; надпись)

Comment: Умер художник Дмитрий Врубель, автор знаменитого граффити "Братский поцелуй".

Умер художник Дмитрий Врубель, автор знаменитых граффити "Братский поцелуй".

Какой вариант правильный?

Comment: Ух ты, а вопрос-то после *глобального* дополнения как изменился! Теперь и шапку надо заново править.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что имеется в орфографическом и терминологических словарях.

[Граффи́то](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE) — *нескл., **с.***
**Сграффито, граффито** — (от итальянского *sgraffito*, буквально — выцарапанный) разновидность монументально-декоративной живописи, принцип которой основан на процарапывании специальными инструментами верхнего тонкого слоя штукатурки до обнажения нижнего слоя, по цвету контрастного верхнему. В древности принцип сграффито применялся в керамике (архаические вазы Греции и Этрурии). В XV — XVII вв. сграффито распространилось в Италии как способ украшения стен (в основном фасадов, благодаря особой прочности этой техники), а оттуда проник [*sic*] и другие страны Европы. В XX веке широко использовался в монументально-декоративном искусстве.

[Граффи́ти](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) — *нескл., **мн.***
[Граффити](http://rudictionary.com/kuzhecov/Graffiti-1610.html)
2) Направление в авангардизме последней четверти 20 в., ориентирующееся на самодеятельные уличные росписи молодежных "тусовок"... Для граффити специально отводятся урбанистические зоны, что способствует его вводу в профессиональное русло. Также стиль граффити применяется в станковом и монументальном искусстве (подобно американскому художнику К. Херингу).

Предложение правильное: изображение на Берлинской стене относится к технике "граффити".
Единственное число обычно используется в контексте исторических надписей.
[Граффито трапезита из Фанагории](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/graffito-trapezita-iz-fanagorii/viewer)

**Дополнение после дополнения**

Если следовать букве правил, то надо бы написать *автор знаменитых граффити* (но тогда возникает ощущение, что их, этих рисунков, несколько).

"Импортное" слово не так давно распространилось в языке, поэтому иногда путают не только число, но и ударение. Вот что есть в Нацкорпусе (самое раннее).

― А ведь на церкви, на одном камне **выбито** граффити. [С. М. Голицын. Тайна старого Радуля (**1972**)] (ср. род)
На автора **этой** граффити тоже смотрели мученические глаза Христа, умоляла о помощи Божья Матерь... [П. Д. Малыгин. Дневник (**1976**)] (ж. род)

Средний род обычно выбирают тогда, когда речь идет о единственном экземпляре, одном цельном полотне, а не "куче" разнокалиберных надписей, тем более что в языке все-таки имеется практически такое же по форме (и по смыслу, и по звучанию) слово среднего рода (*граффито*).

Из Нацкорпуса:
*в центре города — громадное граффити: «Луганск — русский город!»;

в Лондоне появилось граффити с российским «меню»;

граффити, если оно делается пером, кистью ― это каллиграфия.*

Вполне возможно, что со временем в словари внесут изменения, которые узаконят средний род для штучных граффити (как со словом ["галифе"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441696/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5)).

Comment: «... узаконят средний род...» //// Средний род застолблён за техникой *сграффито* (часто удряют на О), а у *граффити* на стене есть синоним — наша *роспись*.